# Hidden form value not retrieved or stored

Tags: php, html, forms, post, store

I have a simple form that can store the date and email, through php, but not a specific hidden value.

Goal: To store the hidden value "clubo" to the f.txt . Can you assist please?

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="clubo" value="clubo"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="date-through-echo"/>
    <input required type="email" name="email" placeholder="join!">
    <input type="submit" name="submitclub" value="Join">
</form>
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['submitclub'])){
$clubo = $_POST['clubo'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$file = fopen("f.txt", "a");
fwrite($file, $clubo);
fwrite($file, $date);
fwrite($file, $email);
fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: You nailed it. That was the issue. It was not the test.php. I corrected the issue and it works as it should. Thank you @biesior !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$_POST` array. For security reasons and also to avoid mistakesit is always better to make sure if you want to read from `GET` or `POST`. Of course always you need to check if form's action points to the proper script. Finally, your code can be just shortened and/or optimized:

**form.html**

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="clubo" value="clubo"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="date" value="date-through-echo" /> <!-- no need for readonly for hidden fields -->
    <input required type="email" name="email" placeholder="join!" /> <!-- no need for `multiple` attr for text fields -->
    <input type="submit" name="submitclub" value="Join">
</form>
```

**test.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['submitclub'])) {
    file_put_contents('g.txt',
        'Club: '.$_POST['clubo'] . PHP_EOL .
        'Date: '.$_POST['date'] . PHP_EOL .
        'E-mail: '.$_POST['email']
    );
}
```

or **test.php** if you want to use it in the append mode:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitclub'])) {
    file_put_contents('g.txt',
        'Club: ' . $_POST['clubo'] . PHP_EOL .
        'Date: ' . $_POST['date'] . PHP_EOL .
        'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . PHP_EOL,
        FILE_APPEND
    );
}
```

Final thought:

Although I don't need your requirements, I assume that storing data may be done better with some database engine, starting from SQLITE to some more advanced engines like MySQL, Mongo, and others.

Comment: You're welcome, pls delete reduntant comments ;)